# ROS including headers

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

How can I make that ROS look for headers files in /usr/include directory when compiling?

I want to use some headers present in that folder, but when I include them in my code and make it, the compiler cannot find the header files. Concretelly, I want to use gtkmm.h, in /usr/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm.h. If I include the file like:

```
#include <gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm.h>
```

it works, but it start to ask for another headers. I want it to search in /usr/include for all dependencies.

This is exactly the error I am getting when making the package:

```
cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
[rosbuild] Building package prglade
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/share/roslisp/rosbuild/roslisp.cmake
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/share/rospy/rosbuild/rospy.cmake
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/fuerte/share/roscpp/rosbuild/roscpp.cmake
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE


-- Build files have been written to: /home/ruben/ROS_workspace/prglade/build
cd build && make 
make[1]: se ingresa al directorio «/home/ruben/ROS_workspace/prglade/build»
make[2]: se ingresa al directorio «/home/ruben/ROS_workspace/prglade/build»
make[3]: se ingresa al directorio «/home/ruben/ROS_workspace/prglade/build»
make[3]: se sale del directorio «/home/ruben/ROS_workspace/prglade/build»
[  0%] Built target rospack_genmsg_libexe
make[3]: se ingresa al directorio «/home/ruben/ROS_workspace/prglade/build»
make[3]: se sale del directorio «/home/ruben/ROS_workspace/prglade/build»
[  0%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
make[3]: se ingresa al directorio «/home/ruben/ROS_workspace/prglade/build»
make[3]: se sale del directorio «/home/ruben/ROS_workspace/prglade/build»
make[3]: se ingresa al directorio «/home/ruben/ROS_workspace/prglade/build»
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/main_node.dir/src/main_node.o
In file included from /home/ruben/ROS_workspace/prglade/src/main_node.cpp:5:0:
/home/ruben/ROS_workspace/prglade/src/viewer.h:5:19: error fatal: gtkmm.h: No existe el archivo o el directorio
compilación terminada.
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/main_node.dir/src/main_node.o] Error 1
make[3]: se sale del directorio «/home/ruben/ROS_workspace/prglade/build»
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/main_node.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: se sale del directorio «/home/ruben/ROS_workspace/prglade/build»
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: se sale del directorio «/home/ruben/ROS_workspace/prglade/build»
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45484/ros-including-headers/) by [ruben.gbarriada](https://answers.ros.org/users/3355/ruben.gbarriada/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-10-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-10**:
The ROS build process does not exclude the header files in `/usr/include`. They should be found, most nodes rely on that. Can you please edit your answer and add the exact error messages you get? See http://ros.org/wiki/Support

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-10**:
Can you please provide the error messages you get?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-10**:
Please do not create answers just for discussion or updates. Instead, please always edit your original post in such cases. This is not a forum. I updated your original question with your 'answer' and deleted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To me it seems like the include in viewer.h is not

```
#include <gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm.h>
```

but

```
#include <gtkmm.h>
```

So what you actually need is to add `/usr/include/gtkmm-2.4` to your include path.

To include libraries in CMake, you normally either use cmake's built-in find macros or pkgconfig. Have a look [here](https://live.gnome.org/gtkmm/UsingCMake) to find out how to correctly include gtkmm in CMake.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1